# storing empty python tuple in sqlite different on linux than windows

Tags: python, linux, windows-7, sqlite

I have a python program that stores some data in sqlite3 and I wanted to use it in a different os.

In windows 7 the program works fine, but in Ubuntu 12.04 it doesn't.

The problem is: When I store an empty tuple in my sqlite database (as a string from  `" ".join( ... )` ) and then read it back in windows I get an empty tuple `()`, while in Ubuntu I get `None`.

My test code is:

```
import sqlite3
import os

def adapt_tuple(tpl):
    return " ".join(str(n) for n in tpl)

def get_tuple(s):
    return tuple([int(x) for x in s.split()])

emptytuple=()
goodtuple=(1,2)

sqlite3.register_adapter(tuple,adapt_tuple)
sqlite3.register_converter("tuple_of_ints",get_tuple)

myconn=sqlite3.connect('test.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
myconn.execute("""CREATE TABLE test(number int, tuple tuple_of_ints);""")

goodentry=(1,goodtuple)
emptyentry=(2,emptytuple)

myconn.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?);""", goodentry)
myconn.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?);""", emptyentry)

for row in myconn.execute("""SELECT * FROM test;"""):
    print row

myconn.close()
os.remove('test.db')
```

This gives me an output of:

```
(1, (1, 2))
(2, ())
```

in windows
and:

```
(1, (1, 2))
(2, None)
```

in ubuntu.

I've checked that

```
get_tuple(adapt_tuple(emptytuple))
```

gives the same output `()` in both systems, so it has to be something to do with going through sqlite3.

The output from `sys.version_info` in python is the same in both systems, and so is `sqlite3.version` so I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the operating system.

So in sumarry, my question is:
         Why is this happening? and   How do I make the Ubuntu version return an empty tuple at the end?

Thanks for any reply.
Apple.

**NOTE**

I should have mentioned originally, if I print my `adapt_tuple` output I get `"  "` on both operating systems.

Comment: You are doing relational databases wrong here - you want your data to be in the smallest pieces possible, so concatenating a collection into a string isn't what you want to do. Make a new table, store them separately in there.

Comment: @Lattyware I don't understand what you mean (I'm pretty new to this) could you post a link that could help? (unless it's a short enough explanation to fit in a comment), thanks.

Comment: So instead of storing lots of values concatenated together in a field on this table, you make another table, which contain a foreign key and an item of data. This allows you to store those items separately, rather than encoding them as a string. It's linked to the idea of [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: What Python versions are you using in Windows and Ubuntu? Apparently, the latter's `adapt_tuple` can return `None`.

Comment: @CL Python version is 2.7.3 on both sqlite version is 2.6.0 on both. Though I've just noticed windows has [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] at the end of the python version printout while Ubuntu has [GCC 4.6.3]. Also the `adapt_tuple` returns "  " in both - It's only when going through sqlite3 that the `None` occurs.

Comment: I would be surprised if your sqlite version is actually 2.6.0 since it was released in 2002. You are probably seeing the pysqlite version instead. Check what you get from `import sqlite3; print sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

Comment: @mmgp Thanks, - there is a difference in that output: Ubuntu is using 3.7.9 while windows is using 3.6.21  I'll go have a look at that.

Comment: The actual problem is in `register_converter`, it misbehaves with empty strings.

Comment: @mmgp Thanks, I get the problem now. I guess that's the first step to solving it.

Comment: @Apple there is no other step, what do you mean ?

Comment: @mmgp Well, I still have to change my code..., but more honestly I'm tired right now and didn't see how simple the solution was at first.

Comment: @Apple you found a corner case nevertheless. It is either worth mentioning it in Python docs or the sqlite wrapper in Python has to be modified. In both cases you will still need to change your code, since  obviously only future releases would come with the corrected behavior (that is supposing the module gets patched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It looks like that one of your `sqlite` versions is treating empty string in the return of an adapter as a NULL, and maybe you have different `sqlite` versions that could explain the different behavior.</del>

<del>If that is the case, then you need to modify the adapter in order to not return empty strings.  Then it is also needed to adjust the converter to handle the new format. Here is an example for that:</del>

```
def adapt_tuple(tpl):
    return repr(tpl)

def get_tuple(s):
    if len(s) > 2:
        return tuple(int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(','))
    return ()
```

The actual problem is related to `register_converter`, which relies on `sqlite3_column_blob`. The later returns NULL for a zero-length BLOB (see the [sqlite's documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)). Then in `pysqlite`'s code there is a check in the following form:

```
if (!sqlite3_column_blob(...)) converted_col = Py_None;
```

As a consequence, your converter is never called for empty strings and None is returned.

The problem is that `pysqlite` depends on the behavior of `sqlite3_column_blob`, which might change between `sqlite` versions. In fact, that is the case. Starting on sqlite 3.7.3, `sqlite3_column_blob` was modified to comply with the documentation. Before that, it wouldn't return NULL on empty blobs. So, to be consistent, ensure that your adapter never returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I can not explain the discrepancy between Windows and Ubuntu, though here is a workaround for Ubuntu:

```
def adapt_tuple(tpl):
    return " ".join(str(n) for n in tpl) or ' '
```